# Space between the columns of an image embedded in HTML table (Resmin arasında bulunan boşluklar)

Tags: html, html-table

I am working on HTML. I embed the image in a table. But as you can see this image there are some spaces between the columns. How can I solve this problem?

http://i.hizliresim.com/Y4ypDZ.png

(Turkish: Bu resimde gördüğünüz gibi, sorun resimlerin arasında bir sütun kadar boşluk olmasıdır, bu tablo üzerine, html'de çalışıyorum. Bu sorunu nasıl çözebilirim?)

Comment: Don't use split images in tables? People stopped doing this a long time ago... if you really want to do it, you should have a look at table borders, cellspacing and padding.

Comment: What is the way of this? I'm working on HTML. If a simpler way exists, could you explain me Mr. Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you split the image in the first place, but anyway if you do HTML, you should also do CSS, and here is a simple example of what I think you want to create:

https://jsfiddle.net/0v8t0Lz0/1/

Have a look at the different HTML tags being used (division, image, header, paragraph, link) and how CSS is used to style them. Every part of your site's content should go into a suitable HTML tag, so you get a reasonable semantic structure... here you can for example do:

```
<section>
    <img src="http://lorempizza.com/800/400" alt="kitten">
    <div class="description">
        <h1>Just a little bit of everything you love</h1>
        <p>Can you think of a better way to spend your night? blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
        <p>ANY 2 large pizzas + Tripple Dippers + Drink for $34.95 delivered.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-green" href="#">Order Now</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Then you can use CSS selectors to match the classes or elements and style theme, i.e. define their size, position, margin, padding, colors and so on. For example you can style the hyperlink like a button by matching the classes `.btn` and `.btn-green` in your stylesheet:

```
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #eee;
    background: #999;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.btn-green {
    background: green;
}
```

In CSS a word matches an element, e.g., `p` matches all `<p></p>` elements in your HTML. A word prefixed with a dot matches a class, e.g., `.red` matches elements like `<p class="red"></p>` and `<div class="red">`. A word prefixed with a number sign matches an id, e.g., `#about` matches an element like `<section id="about"></section>`.

You probably want to also have a look at CSS frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: Thanks for help Mr.Simon.